# How to Create downloadable CSV files using PHP (Other then comma sperated)

Tags: php, csv

Hi I want to make downloadable csv (Apostrophe ( ' ) Separated) sheet in php.

I am using code -

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sheet.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('header1','header2','header3'));
```

Now in this i am able to download csv file (comma separated but i want csv file Apostrophe ( ' ) Separated while run the page)

Comment: Why? Oh Why? Why is not CSV sufficient?

Comment: So what does CSV mean - Comma Separated Values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RTM](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

```
  int fputcsv ( resource $handle , array $fields [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' ]] )
```

so:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sheet.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('header1','header2','header3'), "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

All you need to do is specify a delimiter when calling `fputcsv`:

```
fputcsv($output, array('header1','header2','header3'), "'");
```

If you want to then serve the file, all you'd need to do is then output it

```
echo file_get_contents("php://output");
```

Comment: But the download end will get this is a CSV file.